# How deleting image in source directory after upload and move with Postman and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, upload, postman

I'm working on tutorials with Node JS.
So, I write a script for upload file with request postman and move this file from source to destination. This is success !

But now, what I want to do, is deleting this file from source directory ( like cut/paste).

This is my code :

```
// Route for allows users to upload their profile pictures.
app.post('/upload-profile', async(req,res) =>{

try {
    if(!req.files) {
        res.send({
            status:false,
            message: 'No file Uploaded'
        });
    } else {
        // Use the name of the input field to retrieve the uploaded file
        let avatar = req.files.avatar;
        console.log(req.files.avatar.tempFilePath);
        // Use the mv() method to place the file in upload directory
        avatar.mv('./uploads/' + avatar.name);
       // deleteFile(req.files.avatar.path);


        //send response
        res.send({
            status:true,
            message: 'File is uploaded succesfully',
            data: {
                name: avatar.name,
                mimetype:avatar.mimetype,
                size:avatar.size,
                path:avatar.path
            }
        });

    }

}catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
}
});
```

How I can implement deleting this file ?

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks All.

Comment: use file system(fs) api of nodejs. Here is the link - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: I tried like this after the mv method  :    


`fs.unlink(req.files.path, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.toString());
            } else {
                console.warn(avatar + ' deleted');
            }
        }); `

But not working :/

Comment: The code you have above is normally used in client-server applications. And it would be strange (among other things) for the server (which receives the uploaded file) to delete the file on the client. If you are just wanting to move a file around on one machine, your code can be greatly simplified.